# How do I update multiple columns in a table with multiple conditions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Is it possible to run an update query on multiple columns with multiple conditions in MySQL?

```
id name value price instock pp_flag
 1 xyz     23    27       1       9
 2 abc     28    12       0       8
```

For example above is the structure of a table myTable, where I want to run a query like:

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable 
   set value = 25 
 where id = 1 
   and price = 12 
 where pp_flag = 8
```

Just wondering if I can do this in the same query in MYSQL.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: just do: `UPDATE TABLE myTable 
   set value = 25 
 where id = 1 
   and price = 12 
 and pp_flag = 8` 

You cannot use two `Where` clauses. Use conditional operators like `and`, `or`, `not` etc

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you would like to do this

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable  set value = 25  where id = 1
```

and

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable  set price = 12  where pp_flag = 8
```

in a single statement.

You cannot do this as these are two independent WHERE-conditions.

Comment: Please refrain from simply saying it can't be done unless you're absolutely sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple condition to update column of a table .

As per your requirement you can use below query:

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable set value = 25 
 where id = 1 or (price = 12 and pp_flag = 8);
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use and in where clause:

```
UPDATE TABLE myTable 
   set value = 25 
 where id = 1 
   and price = 12  and pp_flag = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by using the inbuilt IF function in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Query for your example would be:

```
UPDATE myTable SET 
value = if(id=1, 25, value), 
price = if(pp_flag=8, 12, price)
```